# Como usar el número del nombre de la tabla como parametro de referencia a una función de Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo una archivo excel con diferentes pestañas, todas con la misma estructura.

En cada hoja tengo una tabla de datos a la que le doy formato de tabla, de forma que Excel las nombra según se van creando (Tabla1, Tabla2, etc).

El tema es que en cada hoja tengo varias celdas en las que uso funciones que deben estar referenciadas a las tablas.

El problema es que, al generar una hoja nueva, y por tanto una tabla nueva, las formulas pierden la referencia y hay que cambiarlas a mano.

Por ejemplo: `=COUNTA(Table3[Reporter Dept])` deberia ser `=COUNTA(Table4[Reporter Dept])` en la siguiente hoja, pero no cambia de forma automática.

He probado a poner en una celda `=CONCATENATE("Table";E5;"[Reporter Dept]")`, siendo E5 una celda donde tengo el nº de la tabla, y pasar el resultado de la función CONCATENATE a la función COUNTA, pero no funciona.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Podrías probar con INDIRECTO pero, honestamente, no compensa. Es mejor reemplazar todas las referencias que tengas a Table3 con Table4 y listo. Recuerda que  puedes reemplazar masivamente las fórmulas desde BUSCAR->REEMPLAZAR. Te llevará, literalmente, 5 segundos

Comment: No se puede, al copiar la hoja y perderse la referencia de la tabla, la referencia de la tabla de excel que se pasa como argumento a la función pasa a `#REF!` y ya no vale el buscar y reemplazar.

Sin embargo, el indirecto si funciona, no es como esperaba hacerlo pero me vale. 

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás copiando la hoja? ¿Probaste a duplicarla en vez de copiae/pegar?

Comment: Me pongo sobre la hoja de plantilla, boton contrario, mover o copiar, y escojo hacer copia. Pero vamos que con lo del indirecto me ha solucionado todo estupendamente. Gracias por la idea.